# Transfer specific column values on another dataframe based on column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

1. Master list of all stations with the corresponding longitude and latitude,
2. Dataframe with data analysis on specific stations only.

Both dataframes have a column called 'ID' which indicates what station is which. Now I want to transfer the lon and lat columns on the master data frame to the specific dataframe, but only when df1$ID cell value matches the df2$ID cell value.

[image: see two data frames here]

Comment: Look into the `merge()` function

Comment: There must be hundreds of worked examples. I suspect that a search using your question title would find several candidates.